# innerHTML: changing HTML element with <select onchange="">

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement, getelementbyid

Javascript Newbie here.

I'm trying to add some functionality to a charity website by allowing users to choose their preferred currency. I'm using a set drop down list with the `select` property. I'm trying to use the `on change` tag to call a JavaScript function with `getElementByID().innerHTML` to change the display of the currency symbol located in a separate `div`.

Sadly, it's not working and I'm not altogether clear on why. :(

Let's take a look at the code, shall we?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function symbolChange() {
            switch (document.getElementById('currencyCode')) {
               case 'USD':
                  document.getElementById("currencySymbol").innerHTML= "$";
                  break;
               case 'EUR':
                  document.getElementById("currencySymbol").innerHTML= "€";
                  break;
               default :
                  document.getElementById("currencySymbol").innerHTML= "$";
                  break;
                }
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>


    <div id='currencySymbol'>
        $
    </div>

    <div id='currencyCode'>
        <select onchange='symbolChange();'>
                 <option name='USD'>USD</option>
                 <option name='EUR'>EUR</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Any thoughts on what I can do to make this work? Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do:

```
<select onchange='symbolChange(this);'>
                 <option name='USD'>USD</option>
                 <option name='EUR'>EUR</option>
        </select>
```

and js

```
function symbolChange(obj) {
var val = obj.value;
switch (val) {
...
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QmDZ6/)

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct in your code:

```
switch (document.getElementById('currencyCode')) {
```

Use this in HTML:

```
<select id="curVal" onchange='symbolChange();'>
     <option name='USD'>USD</option>
     <option name='EUR'>EUR</option>
</select>
```

and change your switch condition by:

```
switch (document.getElementById('curVal').value) {
```